# CefGlue: Throws Unable to find an entry point named 'cef_build_revision' in DLL 'libcef'

Tags: c#

I compiled CefGlue for .NET 3.5 (since provided binaries are for 4.0). Put newly compiled libraries to my project bin folder, but when I try to run my project (Which is, essentially, a copy ox CefGlue.Demo.WinForms) it throws

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'cef_build_revision' in DLL 'libcef'.
```

Although I checked that all libs are in place. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put CEF Binaries on same folder as exe

You can download from here http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/ is a dead link.

Here is a workaround however.

Download the binaries from here:
http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html

I'm using:
09/30/2017 - CEF 3.3163.1671.g700dc25 / Chromium 61.0.3163.91

Download the source from here:
https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/downloads/

Edit the file:
xilium-xilium.cefglue-cc23b14f414c\CefGlue\Interop\version.g.cs

I changed the hash to match:

```
    //public const string CEF_API_HASH_PLATFORM_WIN = "320c07833219b7b5aca7fc04e186eb9c5b4bca31";
    public const string CEF_API_HASH_PLATFORM_WIN = "7073dfbda7859ff1a53ac4d30d6e9d4fc8e96b7e";
```

Build the Windows forms demo.

Copy the files from:
cef_binary_3.3163.1671.g700dc25_windows32\Release*

To:
xilium-xilium.cefglue-cc23b14f414c\CefGlue.Demo.WinForms\bin\x86\Debug

Also copy the resources:
cef_binary_3.3163.1671.g700dc25_windows32\Resources*

To:
xilium-xilium.cefglue-cc23b14f414c\CefGlue.Demo.WinForms\bin\x86\Debug

And then running the demo should work.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that I used older version of CEF compare to what it was referenced there.